# how to set AWS::AccountId in serverless config file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a serverless.yml file that contains the following:

```
  environment:
    accountId: '#{AWS::AccountId}'
    region: us-east-2
```

env.accountId is coming back as undefined.
Where and how do I set that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `${AWS::AccountId}`?

Comment: no the syntax is correct as I see it in many yml files.

Comment: Are you sure? https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

Comment: I am using serverless.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters

Comment: are you sure you have the "serverless-pseudo-parameters" plugin installed/configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the [serverless-pseudo-parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters) installed.

> Install the package with npm: `npm install serverless-pseudo-parameters`, and add it to your serverless.yml plugins list:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

Also, make sure you have AWS credentials available on the machine you are running from.  These are needed to resolve these values.